# Java double input in array

Tags: java, arrays, input

I have question about array input.I have to create program which will enter number n (number of students) and then i have to input index of student,and score.Score has to be from the highest from the lowest.I have made that but problem is that my index won't "follow" my score.Ex.

- n = 3
- Input first number is index,second score!
- 1 - 2
- 2 - 4
- 3 - 5
- Output :
- 1  - 5
- 2  - 4
- 3  - 2
- Well problem is that my index will not appear with my score
- My code is in picture with this:[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZV57.png)

---

```
package danl;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nizovi6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] index = new int[n];
        int[] score = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            index[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            score[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (score[i] > score[j]) {
                    int t = score[j];
                    score[j] = score[i];
                    score[i] = t;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(index[i] + " " + score[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code here rather than posting a picture

Comment: You need to swap elements in your index array when you swap the element in score array

Comment: Better use a model that has index and score as attribute, create a list/array of it and then sort based on the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of you didn't swap `index[]` array:

```
t = index[j];
index[j] = index[i];
index[i] = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you swap your elements in `score` array, do a corresponding swap in `index` array

```
 int t;
 if (score[i] > score[j]) {
    t = score[j];
    score[j] = score[i];
    score[i] = t;

    t = index[j];
    index[j] = index[i];
    index[i] = t;
 }
```

NOTE: There are a lot of other better ways to handle/solve this by using appropriate data structure for this.

---

You can create a separate class for having the score and its position

```
private static class Score {
    private int score;
    private int position;
    Score(int score, int position) {
        this.score = score;
        this.position = position;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return position + " " + score;
    }
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();

List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int score = sc.nextInt();
    scores.add(new Score(score, i + 1)); //Create new Score objects
}
//Your sorting code here
//OR
//scores.sort((s1, s2) -> s1.score - s2.score); //Sort it by increasing scores
//OR   
// scores.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.score));
System.out.println(scores);
```

Comment: i have to know how this finder of largest number works.IF j and i strats from 0 how they can be compered in program when they are the same number.Please explain me that